# return a reference value from a function in rust

Tags: rust, reference

I'm working on a pdf generation application. I have a struct (Document) that owns all pages. Whenever i want to add a page i also want give the caller a borrowed value of the page back, so the document still is the owner of the struct. Like returning a pointer in C.

```
pub struct Document {
    pages: Vec<Page>,
    totalPages: i32,
    _secret: ()
}


pub fn add_page(&mut self, dimension: PageDimension) -> &mut Page {
    let newPage = Page::new(self.pages.len(), dimension);
    self.pages.push(newPage);
    newPage
}
```

Can anyone explain how to achieve what i want.

Comment: Well firstly, you cannot directly reference `newPage` once it has been consumed by the push method. You will need to get a reference to the vector's last element itself. Secondly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641610/return-reference-with-lifetime-of-self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the [`Vec::last_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut) method. You'll have to unwrap the option that it returns, but that should never panic since you just pushed a new element in.

Here's a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should provide one of those yourself if you want faster/better answers. Without one, it's hard to know what exactly is intended. Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) too for some Rust-specific advice for MREs.

```
pub struct PageDimension;

pub struct Page(usize, PageDimension);

impl Page {
    fn new(page_number: usize, dimension: PageDimension) -> Self {
        Self(page_number, dimension)
    }
}

pub struct Document {
    pages: Vec<Page>,
    totalPages: i32,
    _secret: (),
}

impl Document {
    pub fn add_page(&mut self, dimension: PageDimension) -> &mut Page {
        let newPage = Page::new(self.pages.len(), dimension);
        self.pages.push(newPage);
        self.pages.last_mut().unwrap()
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be6b90a8d6d18028dfa154081a9bf9c4)

Just one last thing. To conform with the community naming conventions, `totalPages` and `newPage` should have `snake_case` names, like `total_pages` and `new_page`. The compiler will warn about this.